# Risks of leaving my Redis port open and unsecure?

Tags: ports

I left port 6005 open on a server of mine. Currently, if the server goes down, it won't be much of a loss. But my port 6005 is open for Redis queues and I don't necessarily want to have deal with it going down.

To clarify, port 6005 is open to all connections with no encryption or password. It is on a server with nginx, mySql, etc. All potential users have been warned to not use any real passwords or sensitive data.

What's the risk of leaving a port open and insecure and does it matter that it's just Redis?

Comment: Open as in public on the internet?

Comment: what does this have to do with nginx?

Comment: @rage Yes, public on the internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to your data being exposed, allowing the open internet to access a misconfigured service could allow an attacker to establish a foothold on the server. Attacks have been carried out against redis that add an attackers SSH key to the redis user's authorized_keys file, granting the attacker SSH access.

See this answer for links to other resources about possible risks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33693810

Comment: How much of this attack was relevant to Redis? Would the hacker have to attack my Redis to add the SSH key? Or would the be able to add the ass the SSH key no matter what?

Comment: The ssh key is added through redis, in sort terms the attacker connects to redis and with a couple of commands insert their keys in the host, allowing to directly ssh with redis user permissions. https://github.com/jas502n/Redis-RCE

Answer (score 1):

If someone can connect to the same network segment they can view your redis queries and extract the credentials you are using.  after that they have full access to the redis database, and may be able to perform privilege escalation attacks by modifying session data etc...  if not they'll have to guess the credentials first.